# Collections with compound keys and hierarchical defaults

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I want to store values against keys.

The keys can be compound, with up to two components per key.

I would like to map

```
Compound key {A,null} to Value 1
```

This Value 1 will be the default value for all lookups for keys having A as their first component, UNLESS an exact matching key has been added to the map.

So if I add to the map

```
Compound key {A,Z} having Value 2
```

When I do a look up, I would like ALL look ups of type `{A,*}` to return 1, so `{A,F}` returns 1 as it not specified so falls back to the default.  The exception to this would be `{A,Z}`, which returns 2 as it is explicitly specified.

I can do this from first principles, by checking that an exact key (two components) match exists before checking on a one component match.

However, is there an existing collection that can do this for me?

What if I have an arbitrary number of components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this I use `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`  You can nest that as deep as you like.

Turns out this works fine with nulls:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapOfMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

    //Make one of these for every first key
    Map<String, Integer> mapOfInt = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

    mapOfInt.put(null, 1); 
    mapOfInt.put("Z", 2); 

    mapOfMap.put("A", mapOfInt);


    System.out.println(mapOfMap.get("A").get(null));
    System.out.println(mapOfMap.get("A").get("Z"));
```

Displays:

```
1
2
```

If you want a class to hide the details of all that (and I wouldn't blame you) try this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DoubleKeyMap<K1, K2, V>
{
    Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> mapOfMap;

    public void put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value)
    {
        if (mapOfMap == null)
        {
            mapOfMap = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, V>>();
        }

        if ( ! mapOfMap.containsKey(key1) )
        {
            mapOfMap.put(key1, new HashMap<K2, V>() );
        }

        mapOfMap.get(key1).put(key2, value);

    }

    public V get(K1 key1, K2 key2)
    {
        if ( ! mapOfMap.containsKey(key1) )
        {
            key1 = null;
        }
        if ( ! mapOfMap.get(key1).containsKey(key2) )
        {
            key2 = null;
        }
        return mapOfMap.get(key1).get(key2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DoubleKeyMap<String, String, Integer> bigMap = new DoubleKeyMap<String, String,Integer>();
        bigMap.put("A", null, 1);
        bigMap.put("A", "Z", 2);

        System.out.println( bigMap.get("A", null) );
        System.out.println( bigMap.get("A", "Z") );
        System.out.println( bigMap.get("A", "F") );
    }
}
```

Displays:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks for having a go! I would also need bigMap.get("A", "F") to return 1, falling back to the {A, null} default.

Comment: @user1717259 you mean like that? :)

Comment: Oops! Yes, just like that!

Comment: @user1717259 if you have the answer you need consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Thanks - let me try and get my head round your other solution!

Answer (score 2):

"What if I have an arbitrary number of components?"

Well then suppress the heck out of some warnings and go old school with well hidden raw maps.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 *  Map lookup with arbitrary number of keys, as set with first use of lay()
 *  Missing keys map to null if null key exists
 */
public class MultiKeyMap<K, V>
{
    int expectedNumberOfKeys = -1;
    V value;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map<K, Map> topMap = new HashMap<K, Map>();

    /** Map to value from keys */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public V lay(V value, K... keys)
    {
        if (keys == null)
        {
            //there are no keys.
            expectedNumberOfKeys = 0;
            V oldValue = this.value;
            this.value = value; 
            return oldValue;
        }

        if (expectedNumberOfKeys != -1 && expectedNumberOfKeys != keys.length)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expecting " + expectedNumberOfKeys + " keys.  Was " + keys.length );
        }

        expectedNumberOfKeys = keys.length;

        Map<K, Map> currentMap = topMap; 

        //all but last key
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++)
        {
            K key = keys[i];

            currentMap = linkToNextMap(currentMap, key);
        }

        //last key
        V oldValue = ((Map<K,V>)currentMap).put(keys[keys.length - 1], value); 
        return oldValue;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    Map<K,Map> linkToNextMap(Map<K,Map> map, K key)
    {
        Map<K, Map> nextMap = null;

        if ( ! map.containsKey(key) )
        {
            map.put(key, new HashMap<K, Map>() );
        }

        nextMap = map.get(key);

        return nextMap;
    }

    /** 
     * Get value maped from keys.  Must include as many keys as laid down.  
     * Keys not found are taken as null keys 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public V get(K... keys)
    {
        if (keys == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        //System.out.println(topMap+" <- topMap");//TODO remove

        if (expectedNumberOfKeys == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (expectedNumberOfKeys == 0)
        {
            return value;
        }

        if (expectedNumberOfKeys != keys.length)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expecting " + expectedNumberOfKeys + " keys.  Was " + keys.length );
        }

        Map<K, Map> currentMap = topMap;

        //All but last key
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++)
        {
            currentMap = (Map) getDefault(currentMap, keys[i]);
        }

        //Last key
        V result = (V) getDefault(currentMap, keys[keys.length - 1]);

        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Object getDefault(Map map, K key)
    {
        Object result = null;

        if (map != null)
        {

            //Use default key (null) if not found
            if ( ! map.containsKey(key) )
            {
                key = null;
            }

            result = map.get(key);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Build {null={D=4, null=3}, A={null=1, Z=2}} 
        MultiKeyMap<String, Integer> map2 = new MultiKeyMap<String, Integer>();
        map2.lay(1, "A", null);
        map2.lay(2, "A", "Z");
        map2.lay(3, null, null);
        map2.lay(4, null, "D");
        System.out.println(map2.get("A", null)); //1        
        System.out.println(map2.get("A", "Z"));  //2
        System.out.println(map2.get("A", "F"));  //1 F not found so treating as null
        System.out.println(map2.get(null, null));//3 
        System.out.println(map2.get(null, "D")); //4
        System.out.println(map2.get("F", "D"));  //4 F not found so treating as null
        System.out.println();

        //Build {null={D={C=4}, null={C=3}}, A={null={B=1}, Z={B=2}}} 
        MultiKeyMap<String, Integer> map3 = new MultiKeyMap<String, Integer>();
        map3.lay(1, "A", null, "B");
        map3.lay(2, "A", "Z", "B");
        map3.lay(3, null, null, "C");
        map3.lay(4, null, "D", "C");
        System.out.println(map3.get("A", null, "B")); //1   
        System.out.println(map3.get("A", "Z", "B"));  //2
        System.out.println(map3.get("A", "F", "B"));  //1 F not found so treating as null
        System.out.println(map3.get(null, null, "C"));//3
        System.out.println(map3.get(null, "D", "C")); //4
        System.out.println(map3.get("F", "D", "C"));  //4 F not found so treating as null
    }   
}
```

Displays:

```
1
2
1
3
4
4

1
2
1
3
4
4
```

I know no one is going to vote for this but I couldn't sleep until I got it out of my head.

Good night SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following requirement is impossible to fulfill with a simple `Map` :

`When I do a look up, I would like ALL look ups of type {A,*} to return 1, with the exception of {A,Z}, which returns 2.`

Indeed, imagine that it is possible and that `map.get(new Compound(A,B))` returns the value associated with `new Compound(A,null)`. Then, it would mean that `new Compound(A,B)` and `new Compound(A,null)` would have the same hashcode and are equal. Now, if I do `map.put(new Compound(A,B),3)`, it is going to overwrite the value associated with `new Compound(A,null)`, which is not what you want.

You need to implement your own type to do this. The implementation could wrap a `Map<Compound<T1,T2>,Integer>` for compound values with a non-null second component and a `Map<T1,Integer>` for the others. You would first look up into the first map, and if you don't find a match you try with the second one. I don't see any way to extend it to any number of components in a smart way.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't thoroughly thought of any potential implications to other methods, but what you could do is overwrite `Hashmap.get()`

`public V get(Object key) {
         V ret = super.get(key);
         if (ret==null){
            //safe cast to Compound key
            Compound c=...;
            ret = super.get(new Compound(c.firstPart, null));
         }
         return ret;
}`

You can create a Compound key that allows more constituents and you can also define the order that it does so.
e.g.
Compound.getGeneralizedKey() that return a new Compound nullifying constituents in the order of your search.

Having said that, note that each of your `get` operations will now be an O(n) operation. i.e. For each `get` you will need to execute `get` n times.

PS. If you don't need to implement the `Map` interface, it would be better if you overrode `Hashmap` adding a safer method like `getRecursive(Compound key)`